# How to connect react-hook-form ref with a custom input component

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

I'm interested in using [react-hook-form](https://react-hook-form.com/) for data validation. I have a custom `TextField` component as follows.

**`src/components/Fields.js`**

```
function Label({ id, children }) {
  return (
    <label
      htmlFor={id}
      className="block mb-3 text-sm font-medium text-gray-700"
    >
      {children}
    </label>
  );
}

export function TextField({
  id,
  label,
  inputRef,
  type = "text",
  className = "",
  ...props
}) {
  return (
    <div className={className}>
      {label && <Label id={id}>{label}</Label>}
      <input id={id} ref={inputRef} type={type} {...props} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

I've tried using `react-hook-form` like this..

**`src/App.js`**

```
import { TextField } from "./components/Fields";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import { useEffect } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    watch,
    formState: { errors },
  } = useForm();
  const mytest = register("mytest", { required: "mytest is a required field" });

  const onSubmit = (data) => console.log(data);

  useEffect(() => console.log(errors), [errors])

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
      <TextField
        id="mytest"
        name={mytest.name}
        inputRef={mytest.ref}
        label="This is a test"
        placeholder="Placeholder"
      />
      <input type="submit" />

    </form>
  );
}
```

but it's not working properly.

[image]

I've also tried using [`forwardRef`](https://beta.reactjs.org/reference/react/forwardRef) to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

Finally got this working after applying [`forwardRef`](https://beta.reactjs.org/reference/react/forwardRef) properly. Still curious if there's a better way, so I'll leave this question open.

**`src/components/Fields.js`**

```
import { forwardRef } from "react";

function Label({ id, children }) {
  return (
    <label
      htmlFor={id}
      className="block mb-3 text-sm font-medium text-gray-700"
    >
      {children}
    </label>
  );
}

export const TextField = forwardRef(function TextField({
  id,
  label,
  type = "text",
  className = "",
  ...props
}, ref) {
  return (
    <div className={className}>
      {label && <Label id={id}>{label}</Label>}
      <input id={id} ref={ref} type={type} {...props} />
    </div>
  );
});
```

**`src/App.js`**

```
import { TextField } from "./components/Fields";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import { useEffect } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    watch,
    formState: { errors },
  } = useForm();
  
  const mytest = register("mytest", { required: "mytest is a required field" });

  const onSubmit = (data) => console.log("data", data);

  useEffect(() => console.log(errors), [errors])

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
      <TextField
        id="mytest"
        label="This is a test"
        placeholder="Placeholder"
        {...mytest}
      />
      {errors.mytest && <>{errors.mytest.message}</>}
      <input type="submit" />

    </form>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The poster's own answer works perfectly. But it fails if the field has a default value that comes from an async function. That would be the case on an update form, for example. You can test by adding this to the form component:

```
const [product, setProduct] = useState({});
useEffect(() => {
  const getProduct = async () => {
    setProduct({ mytest: 'mytestvalue' });
  };
  getProduct();
}, []);
```

and passing the value to the TextField component like

```
(...)
id="mytest"
defaultValue={product.mytest}
```

and of course modify the TextField to receive and use a defaultValue parameter. For testing, click the submit button without modifying the default field value ("mytestvalue" in my example). The app will think the field is empty and show an error message "mytest is required field".

The only solution I have found includes [form reset](https://react-hook-form.com/docs/useform/reset) with a values parameter. Also the error handling is different in this example. `Page.tsx`:

```
'use client'
// 'use client' is necessary here if you use Next.js
import TextField from "./Fields";
import { useForm, FormProvider } from "react-hook-form";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const methods = useForm();
  const [product, setProduct] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    const getProduct = async () => {
      const results = await { mytest: 'mytestvalue' }
      setProduct(results);
      // reset is necessary to register fields even with their default vals
      methods.reset(results);
    };
    getProduct();
  }, [methods]);

  const onSubmit = (data) => console.log("data after submit ", data);

  return (
    <FormProvider {...methods}>
      <form onSubmit={methods.handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
        <TextField
          val={product.mytest}
          id="mytest"
          className='myclassname'
          validations={{ required: "mytest is a required field" }}
          err={methods.formState.errors.mytest }
        />
        <input type="submit" />
      </form>
    </FormProvider>
  );
}
```

`Fields.tsx`:

```
import { useFormContext } from "react-hook-form"

export default function TextField(
  { val, id, type = "text", className = "", validations, err, ...props }) {
  const { register, formState: { errors }, } = useFormContext()
  console.log('err is ', err)

  return (
    <div className={className}>
      <input {...register(id, validations)} id={id} defaultValue={val} type={type} {...props} />
    { err && (<p> {err.message} </p>) }
    </div>
  );
};
```